# Spacing issue in a html string

Tags: php

On my website I have a section with announcements and now I'm working at a tool which will allow moderators to edit or post new announcements.
When a moderator posts an announcement he has a form with an input for the title and a textbox for the content of the article. I use nl2br() function (to insert HTML line breaks before all newlines) in the variable which contains the content of the article.
So when I insert an article in the database it will look like this:

```
First row ...<br />Second row.<br /><br />Regards,<br />Moderators team
```

When a moderator wants to edit an article I have a textbox which containes the article:

```
<textarea name="body" maxlength="1000" cols="105" rows="10"><?php echo str_replace('<br />', "\n", $content); ?></textarea>
```

If the moderator click save button (whithout making any modification) the article becomes something like this (the number of 
 tags doubles):

```
First row ...<br /><br />Second row.<br /><br /><br /><br />Regards,<br /><br />Moderators team
```

Can anybody help me to fix this.

Comment: It looks like it has been through the nl2br() function for a second time.

Comment: you shouldn't insert the html breaks in to the db, but add them when displaying the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save to the database, don't convert the new lines. If you only convert them when you present in the HTML page on the fly, you won't need to convert them back when you echo out to a textarea instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is nl2br: 
Inserts HTML line breaks **before** all newlines in a string
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

So after nl2br you will have **both** the newlines and the `<br />`-tags

Try `$content = preg_replace("~\r?\n~", "<br />", $content);`, which replaces newlines instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do not replace newlines when saving to DB.

Comment: From where do you infere he's not escaping the inputs? :o

Comment: this also depends on the method used to insert. if he uses prepared statements, there won't be any problem with inserting direct input.